# Cannot read property 'columns' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to read json data from server and map. When I enter the same data with hand as a list to the code. It works. But when I am trying to read data from the server it does not work. I know problem is in mapping but I could not figure out. What can be the problem? This is code and json data. Thanks

```
 class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      boards: {
        id: null,
        name: null,
        owner: null,
        columns:[]
      }
    };
  }

  getBoard() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/boards/2")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(list => console.log(list))
      .then(list => this.setState({boards: list}));
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getBoard();
  }
     {this.state.boards.columns.map((column, columnIndex) => (<Column
            status={this.state.addModalShow}
            onModalShow={this.onModalShow}
            onHide={addModalClose}
            addCard={this.addTask}
            column={column}
            columnIndex={columnIndex}
            key={columnIndex}
            onMoveLeft={cardIndex => this.handleMove(columnIndex, cardIndex, DIRECTION_LEFT)}
            onMoveRight={cardIndex => this.handleMove(columnIndex, cardIndex, DIRECTION_RIGHT)}
            onAddCard={() => this.handleAdd(columnIndex)}
            deleteColumn={() => this.deleteColumn(columnIndex)}
            addColumn={() => this.handleAdd()}
            deleteTask={cardIndex => this.deleteTask(columnIndex, cardIndex)}/>))}
```

```
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Board3",
          owner: "Ali",
          -columns: [
            -{
              id: 5,
              name: "eee",
              cards: [
                -{
                  id: 5,
                  name: "TestA",
                  description: "Desc",
                  link: "google.com",
                  deadline: "2013-04-06"
                }, 
               -{
                  id: 8,
                  name: "testB",
                  description: "Desc",
                  link: "google.com",
                  deadline: null
                }
              ]
            }, 
           -{
              id: 6,
              name: "ff",
              cards: []
            }
          ]
      }
```

Comment: Are you sure your state is getting set? Also use componentDidMount()
 instead of componentWillMount as per documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting

Comment: yes, I print the list, it displays in the console

Comment: Format the code properly

Comment: I used componentDidMount() nothing changed. I guess problem is in mapping

Comment: Yes code is in render method. Ok I will fix

Comment: Can you update the getBoard like below: getBoard() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/boards/2")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(list => this.setState({boards: list}))
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you don't return anything inside the function that prints the response to the console. Please read about Promise chaining.

Either return list in your second 'then' block or remove it completely.

Comment: Yes problem was related to  ".then(list => console.log(list))."  I deleted this and it worked. Thanks